# Is there a way to paste 2 "ftable" object?

Tags: r, survey, crosstable

I`m using `svyby` from `survey` to make some weighted ratios with their standard deviation and coefficient of variation, I use the code below to generate a three way table which provide me the ratio of `subocup` compared to `ocup` for male teleworker `Hombre_subocup/ocup`, female teleworkers `Mujer_subocup/ocup` and the exact same for non teleworkers males and females.

```
tasasub_tele_sex319<-ftable(svyby(~subocup, by= ~ tele_sinco11 + SEX, subset(sd319, EDA >= 15 & POS_OCU != "Trabajadores sin pago"), denominator = ~ocup, deff= T, level = 0.9, vartype = c("cv", "se"), na.rm.by =  T,svyratio))

tasasub_tele_sex319
```

And get:

```
                        SEX_
tele_sinco11_             Hombre_subocup/ocup Mujer_subocup/ocup
  No teletrabaja_svyratio         0.084149460        0.080230723
  No teletrabaja_cv               0.001782653        0.002152965
  No teletrabaja_SE               0.021184369        0.026834665
  No teletrabaja_DEff             3.896438704        3.593164119
  Teletrabaja_svyratio            0.036515518        0.027384514
  Teletrabaja_cv                  0.003075113        0.002250647
  Teletrabaja_SE                  0.084213867        0.082186856
  Teletrabaja_DEff                2.325352651        2.039503624
```

But I also need the total value of the ratio (without SEX), so I use this code and get this output:

```
tasasub_tele_tot319<-ftable(svyby(~subocup, by= ~ tele_sinco11, subset(sd319, EDA >= 15 & POS_OCU != "Trabajadores sin pago"), denominator = ~ocup, deff= T, level = 0.9, vartype = c("cv", "se"), na.rm.by =  T,svyratio))

tasasub_tele_tot319

>tasasub_tele_tot319

                        subocup/ocup
tele_sinco11                         
No teletrabaja svyratio   0.082730583
               cv         0.001537011
               SE         0.018578512
               DEff       4.722529515
Teletrabaja    svyratio   0.031475714
               cv         0.001902234
               SE         0.060434971
               DEff       2.299934447
```

This would be the value of the ratio without any strata (a simple two way table).

What I want to do is to paste the last output to the former, so I get a male ratio column, female ratio column and total ratio column in the same table, so more or less it should look like this:

[image]

I wouldn't mind if the "total" columns goes first.

Comment: this seems like a useful question that might help a lot of people!  would it be possible for you to edit it to include a minimal reproducible example?  perhaps pull some starting code from `?svyratio` or `?svyby`

Comment: Sorry, I've been triying to make a simple reproducible example but got this error when try to make de `ftable()` `Error in tmp[ind] <- charQuote(lst[[i]]) : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts` 

`

Comment: maybe create a minimal reproducible example with `dput(tasasub_tele_tot319)` and `dput(tasasub_tele_sex319)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to combine first, then `ftable`. Let's do this with a built-in data set:

```
> a<-svyby(~api.stu,denom=~enroll, ~stype+sch.wide, dclus1,svyratio)
> b<-svyby(~api.stu,denom=~enroll, ~stype, dclus1,svyratio)
> a
      stype sch.wide api.stu/enroll se.api.stu/enroll
E.No      E       No      0.8794583        0.01429043
H.No      H       No      0.8386232        0.01170588
M.No      M       No      0.8390440        0.01478048
E.Yes     E      Yes      0.8508618        0.01231925
H.Yes     H      Yes      0.8286597        0.01622480
M.Yes     M      Yes      0.8589915        0.01272169
> b
  stype api.stu/enroll se.api.stu/enroll
E     E      0.8532672        0.01253361
H     H      0.8300683        0.01472607
M     M      0.8536738        0.01114203
```

These have different column names, but we can fix that

```
>  b$sch.wide<-"Total"
> b
  stype api.stu/enroll se.api.stu/enroll sch.wide
E     E      0.8532672        0.01253361    Total
H     H      0.8300683        0.01472607    Total
M     M      0.8536738        0.01114203    Total
```

And now combine them

```
> ftable(rbind(a,b))
               sch.wide             No            Yes          Total
                        api.stu/enroll api.stu/enroll api.stu/enroll
stype                                                               
E     svyratio              0.87945833     0.85086183     0.85326723
      SE                    0.01429043     0.01231925     0.01253361
H     svyratio              0.83862316     0.82865975     0.83006825
      SE                    0.01170588     0.01622480     0.01472607
M     svyratio              0.83904396     0.85899149     0.85367375
      SE                    0.01478048     0.01272169     0.01114203
```